# mfc project : How to change the caption message that must be in AFX_IDS_APP_TITLE?

Tags: mfc, title, caption

In application created by wizard I have caption that looks like 
'MyApplication - no name'.

So how to change the last sentence 'no name'. I read that string must be in resource with `AFX_IDS_APP_TITLE` id. But changes of them don't make any sense.

I know that I can override the mehtod `PreCreateWindow`, use `SetTitle` and so on.

But I wanna especially use the resource with id `AFX_IDS_APP_TITLE` .
Also, I will appreciate for another solution via resources.

[image]

Comment: What Kind of application did you create? SDI, MDI, dialog based? Did you read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wsw23xx9.aspx?

Comment: @WernerHenze SDI "If this argument is not supplied or is NULL, CWinApp uses the resource string AFX_IDS_APP_TITLE" , but I don't why I can't notice that usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no resource-based solution here.

The best approach to get rid of document file name in app title is to override:

```
BOOL CMainFrame::PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs)
{
    cs.style &= ~(LONG) FWS_ADDTOTITLE;   
    return CFrameWnd::PreCreateWindow(cs);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have seen that solution , and it seems have to reconcile with it